# ReactJS onChange event for reading image fails to update setState value to display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that when rendered, obtains an image in base64 from parent controller and stores it in a state to later display it. There is a button to obtain a new image by updating the state value, but is not updating it and after reading a lot of it online and trying different approaches, I haven't been able to fix it.

Is there anything incorrectly that I'm doing or any advice you can give me? Last thing I tried was using setEffect, but since the state is first established when rendering, I ignore how to make it change the state based on the new value.

Here is the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import change_icon from '../../../../../../icons/switch_image.png'
import delete_icon from '../../../../../../icons/delete.png'


export default function ImageDescriptionComponent(props){
    const IMAGE_FORMAT = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'
    var [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(IMAGE_FORMAT+props.image);
    let id = props.id
    let is_deleteable = props.is_deleteable

    function readImage(event){
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = (e) => {
            var content = reader.result;
            setSelectedImage(content)
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    return (
        <div key={id} className='media_image_div'>
            <img className='media_image' src= {selectedImage}/>
            <div className='image_actions_div'>
                <div className='delete_icon_div'>
                    <img className='image_options_icons' src={delete_icon}/>
                </div>
                <div className='update_icon_div'>
                    <input type="file" accept="image/jpg" id="upload" 
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        readImage(event)
                    }} hidden/>
                    <label htmlFor="upload"><img className='image_options_icons' src={change_icon}/></label>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks ok to me though I'd use the _load_ event (_loadend_ triggers on success **or failure**). So is the issue that adding an image to the `<input type="file">` doesn't update the `img.media_image` element to show the new image?

Comment: @Phil exactly, is not updating the selectedState state variable and I don't understand why

Comment: Can you provide a running demo using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), it works fine for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nziuvt?file=src%2FApp.tsx